# One Wireless Card: Connect to Internet and share it at same time

Tags: wireless-networking, internet-sharing, wifi-configuration, virtual-wifi

Is it possible to get Internet through a single Wireless Lan and share it at same time (I mean share by WiFi not LAN or additional Wireless Lan)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the answer:

It's possible by using [Microsoft Virtual Wifi](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/994abd5f-53d1-4dba-a9d8-8ba1dcccead7/) we can use our normal mode for connecting with Internet and then (right click on WAN -> Property -> Share (Select Virtual Wifi)) I tested tonight :) it was working fine.